# Access Parent Page ViewState from the user control?

Tags: asp.net

is there any way to access parent page ViewState from the user control.

Comment: `Yes` you can ........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) property of the `Page` class is `protected`. Therefore, there's no way to access it from a user control, unless you're willing to break encapsulation by using [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).

Comment: I hate it when time-scales force you to use these inelegant techniques and acrue technical debt :S But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 11):

`Yes` you can ... To do so you just need to follow a `basic trick` ..

`First` **inherit** the caller `page` by a `base page` (using a base page over the project always a `good practice` it help later very much) like below ...

```
public abstract class BasePage : Page
{
  public StateBag ViewState
  {             
     get
       {
          return base.ViewState;
       }
  }
}
```

`Later` you can call this property from `usercontrol` ........

```
var CallerPage = this.Page as BasePage;
if (CallerPage!=null)
{
  var CallerPageViewState = CallerPage.ViewState;
  //Do your rest job
}
```

Comment: Based on this, all my dynamically loaded user controls can now use the single main page's viewstate for storing and retrieving shared item ids. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a word no.  Depending on what you want to do though there may be another way to do what you're trying to achieve

More information on what you're wanting to achieve will help people to answer your question more fully